# passing multiple foregain values in sql cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables tb_schools(school_id,school_name), tb_programms(pid,p_name,school_id)

If suppose multiple schools offer the same program then how can I design the DB.
I mean can I pass the list of school_ids like[sc1,sc2,sc3] in school_id of tb_programms.

note: I can't add multiple rows for a single program.

Comment: Have table linking programs and schools by referencing a program and a school per row.

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you add multiple rows for a single program, just like you would in any other normalised environment

Comment: @Strawberry I can't do that because I'm adding a new column in a live db and that's the constrain  asked by the client

Comment: I think I'd find a less unreasonable client. Their present design is not fit for purpose

Comment: @stickybit I didn't get what you are saying. Are you saying that creating a new table to link both of them?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple schools offer the same program you need to design your schema differently. The canonical solution would be to have a table for schools, a table for programs, and a mapping table for the programs held at each school. E.g.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tb_schools (
    school_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    school_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tb_programs (
    pid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    p_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tb_school_programs
    sid INT NOT NULL,
    pid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid, pid),
    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES school(school_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES programs(pid)
);
```